# Fetching Multiple Rows, but Updating only One php

Tags: php, mysql

How do you update only one row when you fetch for multiple rows? I am lost on how to do this. I can fetch for one row, update and it works. However, I'm stuck for multiple rows.

Down below is my code

FETCH PHP:

```
//loop through for results
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<tr><td>"   
    . $row['title']."<input type='hidden' value='".$row['title']."' name='title'>"
    . "</td><td>"
    . $row['author'] 
    . "</td><td>"
    . $row['summary'] 
    . "</td><td>"
    . $row['isbn']
    . "</td><td>"
    . "<img src='books/".$row['image']."' width='100%'/>" 
    . "</td><td>"
    . "$<input type='text' value='".$row['price']."' size='8' class='pricetoright' name='price'>"
    . "</td><td>"
    . "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btngreen' name='update'>Update</button>"    
    . "</td><td>"
    . "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btnred' name='delete'>Delete</button>"    
    . "</td></tr>";
}
```

UPDATE PHP:

```
// Check Connection
if(!($db = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database))) {
    die('SQL ERROR: Connection failed: '.mysqli_error($db));
} 

$price = floatval($_POST["price"]);
$title = $_REQUEST["title"];

// SQL to update a record
$query = "UPDATE books SET price = '$price' WHERE title = '$title'";

if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
}

mysqli_close($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use form tag for each row. Also its better to use unique id to update row instead of title. So take hidden input of id.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to add a foreach() statement into your code. While it's a little unclear on your code here's a possible example:

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){

 if($k === "title"){
    $title = $_POST["title"];
 }

 if($k === "price"){
    $price = floatval($_POST["price"]);
 }




// SQL to update a record
$query = "UPDATE books SET price = '$price' WHERE title = '$title'";

   if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
   } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. This only updates the last row, but doesn't update the rest.

Comment: notice how I said possible example... modify to suit your needs.